# Keep background from changing color on .dropdown-toggle component

Tags: html, css

I've got this bit of code here: (Update: I put the entire navbar code here now because I realized with the limited amount originally posted may be limiting the ability to figure out the problem)

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navsize">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" ><img id="logo" src="/Images/SC2_MyLink_Logo.png" alt="SC2 Logo"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul id="navposition" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="individualbtnposition col-lg-2">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
            <li class="dropdown individualbtnposition">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Our Company<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Our History", "Index", "OurCompany")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Facilities", "Facilities", "OurCompany")</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown individualbtnposition">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Employee Services<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Forms</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("HR Forms", "HRForms", "FormsHandlers")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Corporate Forms", "CorporateForms", "FormsHandlers")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Employee Benefits", "EmployeeBenefitsForms", "FormsHandlers")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Accident Forms", "AccidentForms", "FormsHandlers")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Payroll Forms", "PayrollForms", "FormsHandlers")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pay Stubs</a></li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("FAQ", "FAQ", "FormsHandlers")</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown individualbtnposition">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Support Services<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">IT Support</a></li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Purchasing Ticket", "OnlineForms", "FormsHandlers", new {id = "purchasing-services-form" })</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Maint. Support</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="logout col-lg-1">
    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Logout">Sign Out</a>
</div>
```

On the class="dropdown-toggle", when a menu button is clicked, it changes the square around it to black. I don't want it to change color, but I can't seem to figure out how to keep it from doing it. The only thing I could figure out was if I put this code in:

```
  .dropdown-toggle{ background: white; }
```

Then it changes the background white before clicking it. So I can effect the color before clicking, but after clicking I can't seem to get it to just not be changed at all. Any ideas? Here is a picture of what it is doing for a reference:
[image]

Comment: have you tried background: initial; or transparent?

Comment: There's no `.data-toggle` class so try `.dropdown-toggle`

Comment: I think the problem is that when I'm manipulating .data-toggle{}, that is changing it's initial state, not it's clicked state. I can't seem to figure out how to modify it's clicked/open state.

Comment: @zer00ne that was my fault, a typo. The actual code is dropdown-toggle. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: `.dropdown-toggle` is the class for an anchor tag, so add the pseudo-classes `:link`, `:visited`,  `:hover`, and `:active` (in that particular order). Also, Bootstrap has very high specificity so you can try to double up on classes as well (ex. `.dropdown-toggle.dropdown-toggle`)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still fairly new with html and css, do you mean like this: .dropdown-toggle :link :visited: hover :active {} , all together?

Comment: ex. `.dropdown-toggle:link, .dropdown-toggle:visited {}` `.dropdown-toggle:hover, .dropdown-toggle:active {}` is the most common configuration.

Comment: So I tried .dropdown-toggle:link{background: initial;} and also with background: transparent; and I tried that also with visited, hover, and active, individually and all at once. I didn't any change though. I also cleared the cache every time to make sure any new changes were visible.

Comment: ... Isn't it obviously the <li> not the <a> ? .dropdown {background-color: purple !important}. Threw an important on there to make sure target is correct. Just go through your html in inspector and see which element it is and set that background color to something different

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm sorry, like I said I'm still fairly new to some of this stuff. It would make sense to modify the li since it's the individual block changing. How best to access that though?

Comment: I added the rest of the navbar code incase that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the dev tools to narrow it down to exactly what was putting the black there, then I just manually changed it. here is the piece of css that I put in to fix it:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
color: #fff;
background-color: initial;
```

}